# repeated add/remove results in memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, cytoscape.js

I have a use case where I repeatedly fetch data from the server and display it using cytoscape. For this, I just have a single cy object and I repeatedly remove and add the elements. This happens once every second or two. I notice the browser memory growing with time. The documentation says "Though the elements specified to this function are removed from the graph, they may still exist in memory"

So, do I need to do anything with the collection returned by calling remove? How do I ensure memory is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Well javascript is already a [garbage collected language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management), so it will drop all of your references to your nodes eventually. If you remove nodes from the graph and you don't have any references to it, then the garbage collector will clean it up ... eventually :)

Due to the fact that these memory leaks exists, my educated guess is, that there may be some internal entanglement with a global scope or sth like that which prevents elements to be discarded before the whole graph is reinitialized (maybe try that?).